# How to scroll to bottom on click of text in javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, hover

I am working on a website in which I want to scroll towards the bottom on click of a text in javascript/jquery.

```
<p  class="ml-2 mb-2 d-flex  view_profile_options"><a href=""> view options</a> <i class="ml-2 fas fa-2x fa-angle-right"></i></p>
```

So on clicking of view options text above, it should take us to the **Paris section** in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/21/embedded/result).

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that on hitting **view options** text, it take us to the **paris** section **tab with hover** and **content** getting **enabled** automatically.

I am pretty sure, I have to use the following jquery code but I am not sure how I can integrate in the current code..

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your jQuery is not binding the click behaviour to the correct `a` element. Consider the following updates:

```
$("p.view_profile_options a") // Causes the logic to attach to the link in 
.click(function(event) {      // your paragraph

    event.preventDefault(); // Causes the default browser behaviour for 
                            // link clicking to not happen

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tab").offset().top}, // Causes the scrolling to the
                                            // .tabs (ie as in your jsFiddle)
        'slow');
});
```

### Updated answer

Here is the updated jQuery that includes the additional functionality for opening the Paris city tab, and activation of that tabs `active` style. An [updated jsFiddle of this can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/84/):

```
/* Causes the logic to attach to the 
   link in your paragraph */
$("p.view_profile_options a") 
.click(function(event) {

  /* Causes the default browser behaviour 
     for link clicking to not happen */
  event.preventDefault(); 

  /* Open the 'paris' tab automatically */
  openCity(event, 'Paris')
  /* Cause the 'paris' tab to be 
     highlighted as active */
  $('.tab .tablinks:nth(1)').addClass('active')

    /* Causes the scrolling to the .tabs 
     (ie as in your jsFiddle) */
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".tab").offset().top},
        'slow');
});
```

Comment: @Dacree Denny I am wondering if you can update it in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/21/embedded/result) In that way, it would be easy for me to visualize.

Comment: Hi @flash, please see updated answer - does this help you?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/56/). This is a function to scroll to bottom:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function scrollToBottom() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$(document).height()}, 'slow');
    }
</script>
```

And all you need to do is call `scrollToBottom()` function from your link, so your entire `<p>` tag should look like this

```
 <p  class="ml-2 mb-2 d-flex  view_profile_options"><a href="javascript:scrollToBottom()"> view option</a> <i class="ml-2 fas fa-2x fa-angle-right"></i></p>
```

EDIT: I edited the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wpy496v3/118/) to go to Paris section specifically.

Comment: I am wondering if there is any way on clicking `view options`, the hover section for `Paris` and `Content` gets enable automatically ??

Answer (score 1):

On clicking view options it will take you the tab section.

```
$(".view_profile_options a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var sectionTop = $('.tab-contents').offset().top;
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: sectionTop },
        'slow');
 });
```

Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/moshiuramit/02znsurj/